# InputStream Cannot Be Null / Can't Access File Inside Another Package

Tags: java

I'm trying to access a file from one class inside another package inside a JAR file. To be more specific, the class in which I'm creating the inputstream is named ClassA.class and is located in the package: com.something.somethingelse while the file I'm trying to open with inputstream is located in the package com.something.storage. I'm calling the getResourceAsStream method as shown below:

```
    ClassA.class.getResourceAsStream("/com/something/storage/MyFile.txt");
```

However, it throws a IllegalArgumentException saying that the inputstream cannot be null. I've tried storing the text file in the same package as ClassA and the problem did not appear. Only when it's stored in another package does this occur. Please help.

It might also be helpful to know that the method I'm doing this in is a static one. Will that have anything to do with the problem?

Comment: Are you sure there is no typo somewhere? And: Please post the exception stack trace.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that there are no typos. As for the stack trace, there is none thrown since the inputstream simply returns null when the file is not found. The exception I was talking about is thrown as part of another method since I used the inputstream as one of it's arguments so that is irrelevant to this situation.

Comment: Have you tried `/../storage/MyFile.txt` ?

Comment: @SoboLAN I guess you shouldn't start with `/`, you're making the path absolute this way. For relative path `../storage/MyFile.txt` is enough.

Comment: @SoboLAN Yes. I have tried defining an absolute path to the file.

Comment: @alain.janinm My text file is not stored in the same package as my class file so I can't get it through a relative path.

Comment: I made a small mistake while writing that comment: I didn't mean writing the absolute path. I meant going up 1 level on the directory tree and then trying to reach the file, like this: `../storage/MyFile.txt`. The `..` means "the parent directory". In the case of Java: packages are directories. I always get these sort of relative paths wrong, because in some situations the `/` in front is needed, sometimes it's not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ClassA.class.getResourceAsStream("/com/something/storage/MyFile.txt");

returns null because the file "/com/something/storage/MyFile.txt" does not exist

Comment: I just tried adding another class in the same package as the text file which will return the input stream but it turns out to be null as well.

Comment: Still returning null when I use getClass()

Comment: post the exception stack trace.ClassA.class.getResourceAsStream("/com/something/storage/MyFile.txt"); works fine

Comment: /com/something/storage/MyFile.txt check if file exists

Comment: No exception is thrown except for an irrelevant one caused by the argument being null when I use the input stream in another method.

Comment: How would I check if it exists or not. I can't define a file for that.

Comment: you must create the file /com/something/storage/MyFile.txt in your project before running your application

Answer (score 3):

In your class inside `com.something.somethingelse` open the stream with :

```
getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("com/something/storage/MyFile.txt");
```

Using `getClassLoader()` you specify the package path in an absolute way (without the first `/`).

Comment: In the end, I created an accessor class that returned the document inputstream using @alain.janinm's code. Thanks guys!

Comment: @RobertLu You're welcome! If my answer is the one that works for you, you should accept mine ;) if other users experienced the same problem it will be easier for them to determine the good answer!